# Symfony Form Submit not Working

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I've recently decided to take the plunge and learn Symfony as before I was learning flat PHP.

I've been following various tutorials about how to add data to a database via a form in Symfony 3.  I have a MySQL table called CRM_PERSON and I'm trying to submit a person's details (a person is known as a "lead" in this project).  For some reason, when I press the submit button on the form, I simply get sent to a standard error page in Google Chrome saying "this site can't be reached.

I've tried following the code exactly from three different tutorials now and various questions on Stack Overflow but I still can't seem to get this to work. I'm sure I must be doing something stupid here!

Here is my code:

**LeadController.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\CrmPersonType;
use AppBundle\Entity\CrmPerson;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;




class LeadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/user/lead", name="lead")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $leads = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:CrmPerson')->findAll();

        dump($leads);

        return $this->render(':lead:lead.html.twig', [
        'leads' => $leads
        ]);
     }


    /**
     * @Route("/user/lead_add", name="lead_add")
     */
    public function leadAdd(Request $request)   
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(CrmPersonType::class);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $crmperson = $form->getData();

            $em->persist($crmperson);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('lead_add');
        }

        return $this->render(':lead:lead.add.html.twig', [
        'leadForm' => $form->createView()
            ]);
    }



}
```

**CrmPersonType.php**

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Form/CrmPersonType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\CrmPerson;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CrmPersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class) 
            ->add('middleNames', TextType::class) 
            ->add('surname', TextType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Save',
                'attr'  => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => CrmPerson::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

**lead.add.html.twig**

```
{# app/Resources/views/lead.html.twig #}

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h1>Add Lead</h1>

            {{ form_start(leadForm) }}
            {{ form_widget(leadForm) }}
            {{ form_end(leadForm) }}

        </div></div></div>



    </body>
</html>




{% endblock %}
```

I'd be really grateful for some pointers in the right direction!

Comment: Please provide logs and make sure you are using `app_dev.php`

Comment: in your template, you use form_start, which is most likely generating an incorrect value for the action attribute on your form.

Comment: @IonBazan, I'm definitely using app_dev.php.  I'll see if I can work out how to get the logs.

Comment: @SamJanssens.  Thanks for pointing this out, do you know what I should be using instead of form_start?

Comment: just render the form tag yourself by outputting the actual html (and using {{ path() }} to point the action attribute to your lead_add )   also,   your lead add action must end in Action  (leadAddAction   not   leadAdd)

Comment: @SamJanssens I've changed the name to leadAddAction() as you've recommended.  Also could you possibly show me an example of what you mean by outputting the actual html please?  It's strange because I've been able to get the form to work in other situations using form_start (when I created the form in the actual controller itself). It just doesn't seem to work when I separate out the form building into the separate CrmPersonType.php file.

Comment: nvm the form_start thing (i thought u had the creation vs handeling of form, in seperate actions, but you dont)   the weird thing is that you say you get a chrome message, i would expect a symfony 500 or something,   check var/logs (or app/logs depending on sf version), for any usefull errors or clues, it sounds like an issue with the redirection, but i dont see it right away

Comment: @SamJanssens I've just done another part of the same tutorial where I put another action in the controller (leadEditAction) and use exactly the same form to edit the database record and it works, submits properly and stores the changes in the data base.  It just doesn't seem to work when I try to create and submit a completely new object. It's really weird!

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a new CrmPerson when creating the form

```
$crmPerson = new CrmPerson();
$form = $this->createForm(CrmPersonType::class, $crmPerson);
```

Comment: I've modified my code to include the new CrmPerson and also to include the $crmPerson in the createForm() and it still takes me to the Google Chrome page not found.  I really can't understand why I can get the form to work when I edit a record but not to add a new one!